# Unable to use custom typed npm package

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've installed a package called **mini-alert** which doesn't have its corresponding types. I've modified the **tsconfig.json** to declaration but when I try to use it my code it throws this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function.

**1. Handling the missing types myself**

```
interface Props{
    overflow?: boolean;    
    autoremove?: boolean;    
    time?: number;        
    size?: string;       
    cartoon?: boolean;      
    limit?: number;            
    text?: string;
}
declare module 'mini-alert'{
    export const miniAlert: (args: Props) => void;
};
```

**tsconfi.json setup**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {   
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "ES2021"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "types"
  ],
  "xexclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*/*.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
  ]
}
```

**Using the package in my code**

```
 const onCopyText = () => {
    setIsCopied(true);
    miniAlert({
      overflow: true, // <-- disable behind the alert
      autoremove: true, // <-- automatic remove
      time: 500, // <-- milliseconds
      size: 'large', // <-- small, medium, large
      cartoon: false, // <-- "cartoon effect" true/false
      limit: 1, // <-- max alerts visible at the same time
      text: 'Copied!'
    });   
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsCopied(false);
    }, 1000);
```

**Expected resul**

I want to see a mini alert popup just like in this [mini alert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-alert)

**Actual result**

When I click a button, I don't see any alert but this in the Chrome dev tools. What am I doing wrong
[image]

**My use case's in a code sandbox**

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-feather-365xn3?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: That's a _runtime_ type error, and not a typescript type error. What is the code in `Dashboard.tsx` on line `89`?

Comment: @AlexWayne, I've updated my post to include a Codesandbox demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code sandbox you are importing `mini-alert` like this:

```
import { miniAlert } from "mini-alert";
```

But [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-alert) says to import it like this:

```
import miniAlert from 'mini-alert';
```

That means that the value you want is the default export from the package, and not a named export.

Which means the types should be something like:

```
declare module "mini-alert" {
  const miniAlert: (args: Props) => void;
  export default miniAlert;
}
```

Comment: @Mo1 please make sure to upvote and accept the answers that helped you. None of your questions have asked over the past year have accepted answers. It helps people in the future know what solutions are valid and it motivates us answerers with made up internet points!

Answer (score -1):

I use Vue.js rather than React, so not sure of the exact implementation, but typically if you are using a package that is JavaScript and you want to use it as TypeScript, you need to create a `.d.ts` file to translate the package. See the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html)

Comment: I've tried that as well but it gives the same error.

Comment: This would do nothing to fix a runtime error, sadly.